# PHP not issuing any notice for undefined variable if the variable is passing to empty() or isset()

Tags: php, notice

```
<?php

function myFunction($yesNname) { } 

empty($noName);
print_r($noName);
isset($noName);

myFunction($noName);
```

output:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: noName ... on line 6 // print_r
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: noName ... on line 9 // myFunction
```

The undefined variable is used in *empty()* and *isset()*. But PHP didn't issue notice about it. Why PHP shows discrimination to some function?  How can I write such type of function?

Comment: What'd the point of having a function to test whether a variable exist, and make it trigger an error message when it doesn't exist?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  I can understand that. I want to know how can I write such type of function.

Comment: Why would you want that? Could you please sketch out the situation?

Comment: @giorgio I thought there will be some technique in PHP to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `isset()` nor `empty()` are functions. As the manual explains:

> this is a language construct and not a function

To get this behaviour you'd need to tweak the PHP source code written in C.

It's possible that you can also get this behaviour with a PHP extension, but you'd also need to write it in C and install it in your server.

**Update:**

- [Manual page for isset()](http://php.net/isset)
- [Manual page for empty()](http://php.net/empty)
- [Guide to the Zend Engine](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.php)

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean like:

```
if(!empty($noName)) {
 // print_r
 // function($noName);
}
```

Comment: Why should I put the condition for calling a function? did you see any such condition around the isset() or empty() in my code?

Comment: Please note that isset is not needed in conjunction with empty (empty does already return false if a var does not exist)

Comment: take it easy @habeebperwad, he's trying to help you... and is right actually

Comment: @giorgio He tried to solve the PHP notice! He didn't tried to answer my question " How can I write such type of function?". Anyway, +1 for considering my question.

Comment: Someone already mentioned it: you can't. And why should you, anyway? The functions are already there, and atomic to boot. Why would you want to replicate something you can just use?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it on function side. If you simply don't want to show errors you can either check variable first before calling function or use [error control operator "@"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).